# C++98 Valid use of "for_each" in the code

Tags: c++, foreach

I want to go directly in the code; Here is my struct:

```
struct pnt {
  mesh::Point _point;
  pnt_type _type;
  bool _aux;
  };

enum NNSerach {A_NN = 0, B_NN, C_NN, ALL};
```

and here is my function:

```
void typeDetection( pnt& PNT, const NNSerach NNType, const fieldclass& field )
```

Here is my for loop inside a member function of the fieldclass.

```
vector< pnt > oldpnTs;
...
  for(size_t iter = 0; iter < oldpnTs.size(); iter++ )
  {
    typeDetection(oldpnTs[iter], ALL, *this);
  }
```

Is it possible to use for_each here, when my vector member is only one of the arguments of the applied function?

**EDIT**: I can only use **C++98**
I want to apply typeDetection function for each member of the oldpnTs vector.

Comment: What? What for_each do you want to use? c++11 range-based for loop?

Comment: EDIT: I can only use C++98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, though that wouldn't make it that much better I'd say, as you'd need to define a functor for `typeDetection`, and then pass it to `for_each` (don't forget to pass `this` and the `NNSearch` value to the functor when you create it so you can pass them to `typeDetection` when needed).

In this case I'd consider keeping the for loop as it is, as the code is readable in its current form, **unless** you have to perform this operation on multiple such vectors with potentially different sizes, resulting in the following:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(oldpnTs), std::end(oldpnTs), typeDetectionFunctor);
std::for_each(std::begin(oldpnTs), std::end(oldpnTs2), typeDetectionFunctor);
std::for_each(std::begin(oldpnTs), std::end(oldpnTs3), typeDetectionFunctor);
std::for_each(std::begin(oldpnTs), std::end(oldpnTs4), typeDetectionFunctor);
//...
```

instead of multiple 4 liners loop like you currently have.

Comment: Yes I have got couple of vectors which I need to apply this function.

Comment: @H'H Then `for_each` can be applied here, if you think having to define and create the functor is not too much hassle to spare the 4 liners loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work (though I couldn't test it because nothing is really defined here). Instead of this part of your code,

```
   vector< pnt > oldpnTs;

   for(size_t iter = 0; iter < oldpnTs.size(); iter++ )
   {
     typeDetection(oldpnTs[iter], ALL, *this);
   }
```

you can try this (in C++14):

```
   vector< pnt > oldpnTs;
   NNSerach all = ALL;
   // ...
   std::for_each(oldpnTs.begin(), oldpnTs.end()
               , [this, all](auto& x) {this->typeDetection(x, all, *this);});
```

---

**EDIT:** in C++98, instead of the lambda you surely can use a functor where you fix the other variables beside `pnt&`. Or you can use `boost::lambda` or `boost::bind`.

Comment: Your EDIT came after my attempts. I'll let it stand if that's ok for you.

Comment: although I cannot use C++14, It is nice to see how it works under new C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

As you use C++98, you should implement lambda function yourself using a functor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct pnt {
  mesh::Point _point;
  pnt_type _type;
  bool _aux;
    };

enum NNSerach {A_NN = 0, B_NN, C_NN, ALL}; 

class fieldclass;

class TypeDetection
{
public:
    TypeDetection(const NNSerach NNType, const fieldclass& field) : _NNType(NNType), _field(field){}
    void operator() (pnt& PNT)
    {
        typeDetection(PNT, _NNType, _field);
    }
private:
    void typeDetection( pnt& PNT, const NNSerach NNType, const fieldclass& field ){}

    const fieldclass& _field;
    const NNSerach _NNType;
};

class fieldclass
{
public:
    void Do()
    {
        std::vector<pnt> oldpnTs;
        std::for_each(oldpnTs.begin(), oldpnTs.end(), TypeDetection(ALL, *this));
    }
};
```