# solving issue # C++98 Valid use of “for_each” in the code using Boost library 1.53 or 1.56

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-foreach

I already asked the question. I am wondering if there is any solution for **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910758/c98-valid-use-of-for-each-in-the-code)** using boost::for_each and boost::bind.

The question has been already answered, that's why I created another issue here; only for the curiosity.
Thanks.

Comment: There is a link on the "this"....can't you click on it?

Comment: This is another case of me not being able to see links due to [the difference in colors being minimal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/make-links-in-stack-overflow-answers-more-obvious). Sorry about the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `boost::bind` to create a suitable functor, with a placeholder for the functor's parameter:

```
for_each(oldpnTs.begin(), oldpnTs.end(), bind(typeDetection, _1, ALL, *this));
```

In modern C++, I'd prefer a new-style loop

```
for (pnt & p : oldpnTs) {
    typeDetection(p, ALL, *this);
}
```